# Collapsible Buttons Not Working on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple website and have three collapsible buttons. Each shows the code of the website itself. They open when clicked on a PC but do not open when clicked on mobile. All that happens is that the button is highlighted. Here is the code I am using.

Javascript:

```
  <script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.collapsible {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: rgb(7, 6, 6);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
    padding: 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<body>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">CSS</button>
<div class="content">
     contents
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">HTML</button>
<div class="content">
     contents2
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">JavaScript</button>
<div class="content">
     contents3
</div>
</body>
```

I have tried adding a touchstart handler to the Javascript but that does not work. Thanks for your help. I apologize if it is an obvious answer, I am new to websites.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is broken. You forgot to open the second div element.

So your HTML should be:

```
<body>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">CSS</button>
  <div class="content">
       contents
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">HTML</button>
  <div class="content">
       contents2
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">JavaScript</button>
  <div class="content">
       contents3
  </div>
</body>
```

And I added some colours to your fonts:

```
.collapsible {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: rgb(7, 6, 6);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
    padding: 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcqwnv8e/)

Comment: Thanks, but the html error was a mistake in my copying of my code. My html works fine. I don't know why the collapsibles won't open on mobile, even after adding a touchstart handler.

Comment: I tried opening jsfiddle on my phone and everything works there. Maybe you could provide a some link?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/emmet/Documents/Mywebpage/CONCEPT/Website%20As%20Idea.html

Comment: I mean a public link. Your link refers to a file on your computer, no one else can view it

Comment: How do you actually check this on your phone?

Comment: My bad. I have been emailing the html file to myself and opening it on my phone.

Comment: Oh. What if you open this link in your phone's browser: https://jsfiddle.net/jcqwnv8e/show

Comment: That works. But not when I email the file to myself. strange

Comment: Nothing strange. This is a very strange way to develop websites for phones. Most likely javascript just doesn't work there (and shouldn't)

Comment: And you can accept solution or vote for it to increase the rating of responders. It's how we are saying thanks here :)

Answer (score 0):

It was not a problem with the code, I just had to publish the website to access it on my phone. It was a problem with the file being locally hosted. Thanks for everyone's replies and help.